# All objects in array (interpreted from csv) being returned as the same object (the last object)

Tags: objective-c

What I am trying to achieve, is to convert a csv file into an array of custom objects, however, my attempts at this seem to result in all of the objects in the array being returned as the same object (the last object in the array).

Before I explain further, here is the code:

```
- (NSArray *)arrayFromCSVFileName:(NSString *)csvFileName fileType:(NSString *)fileType {

// Convert the file into an NSData object
NSString *studentFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:csvFileName ofType:fileType];
NSData *studentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:studentFilePath];

// Convert the NSData into an NSString
NSString *csvString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:studentData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Split each record (line) in the csvDataString into an individual array element (split on the newline character \n)
NSArray *csvArray = [csvString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

// Create an array to hold the parsed CSV data
NSMutableArray *parsedCSVArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

CGSElement *elementToAdd = [[CGSElement alloc] init];

// Loop through each line of the file
for (int i = 0; i < [csvArray count]; i++) {

    // Get a reference to this record (line) as a string, and remove any extranous new lines or alike
    NSString *csvRecordString = [[csvArray objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];

    // Split the line by the comma delimeter
    NSArray *csvRecordArray = [csvRecordString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    // Check that there are actually fields (i.e. this is not a blank line)
    if ( ([csvRecordArray count] > 0) && ([[csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:0] length] > 0) ) {

        elementToAdd.mass = [[csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        elementToAdd.atomicNumber = [[csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        elementToAdd.name = [csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:2];
        elementToAdd.symbol = [csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:3];
        elementToAdd.period = [[csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:4] intValue];

        [elementArray addObject:elementToAdd];

    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < [elementArray count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"%i", i);

    CGSElement *current = [elementArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"Name = %@", current.name);

}

// Return the parsed array
return elementArray;
}
```

The custom object in question is the CGSElement object, which I am attempting to fill the `elementArray` with. However, my debug code (the following section of code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < [elementArray count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"%i", i);

    CGSElement *current = [elementArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"Name = %@", current.name);

}
```

Is resulting, rather than in the return of all of the correct element names, it is returning the last element (to put this in context, ununoctium), 118 times.

After some testing, I can safely say that up until after this point:

```
elementToAdd.mass = [[csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
elementToAdd.atomicNumber = [[csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
elementToAdd.name = [csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:2];
elementToAdd.symbol = [csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:3];
elementToAdd.period = [[csvRecordArray objectAtIndex:4] intValue];
```

All of the elements are being correctly defined, rather than just the same element over and over.

Needless to say, I'm stumped as to why it would be returning the same object over and over. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
CGSElement *elementToAdd = [[CGSElement alloc] init];
```

Should be inside your loop, just before you try to edit the object and add it to the array. Currently you are repeatedly mutating the same object instead of creating new objects for each record.

Answer (score 1):

You add the same entity all the time. It is crated once before the loop and within the loop it values are changed again and angan and it is added to the array. Naturally all items in the aray carry the same values because it is the same object.

If you want then change the array with an NSSet. To a set an object can only added once and you will end up with a set of 1. That is not the solution of couse, it would just visualize what is happening.

To solve it move this line

```
CGSElement *elementToAdd = [[CGSElement alloc] init];
```

to the beginning of the body of the `for i` loop, so that a new instance is created for every iteration and therefore for every index of the array.